# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ldap'

Tags: python, ldap, openldap

I'm trying to query my openldap server and got error 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ldap'

I already tried to install python packages:

pip install python-ldap

pip install pyldap

pip install ldap(got alot of errors for this one)

And I'm still can't run it.

the code is:

```
import ldap
con = ldap.initialize('ldap://192.168.14.129')

con.simple_bind_s("cn=Manager,dc=afik,dc=com","xxxxx")
ldap_base = "dc=afik,dc=com"
query = "(uid=hr_user1)"
result = con.simple_bind_s(ldap_base, ldap.SCOP_SUBREE, query)
```

the error that I getting:

```
[root@localhost GitShared]# python openldap.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "openldap.py", line 1, in <module>
    import ldap
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ldap'
[root@localhost GitShared]#
```

I'm using python 3.6 on a centos 7 machine.

Comment: Can you try using `pip3`?

Comment: If you got a lot of errors with `pip install ldap`, then that is your problem. You will need to troubleshoot the installation first.

Comment: I think it changed to `python-ldap` from `ldap` in python3